# fast approximate string matching in a large array in ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

In Ruby I have an array consisting of about a million strings called `dictionary_array`. I have another array consisting of about thousand strings called `arr`.

For every element in `arr`, I want to find an element in `dictionary_array` which is closest.

Iterating over every element in `arr`, and for each element in `arr` iterating over every element in `dictionary_array` to find the one with the minimum Levenshtein distance is O(n^2) and too slow for my purposes.

Is there a better way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Ruby is not the language for that.

Comment: Define too slow. How long does it take? Can you run it one time and cache the results?

Comment: aquinas, no caching is not possible here

Comment: Could you give examples of the kinds of strings stored in both arrays?

Comment: How do  you compute levenshtein distance in O(1)? Or else, how do you get the O (n^2) bound?

Comment: Wait, so what are you trying to do? Just have aliases for city names? If so, you're WAY over-complicating this. :)

Comment: Thomas dictionary_array consists of city names like New York,Saint Louis etc and arr consists of city names again. If arr contains St. Louis i would like Saint Louis from dictionary_array to match.

Comment: acquinas Its not just aliases, arr could contain misspelled words, and i would like to find the closest match if any

Comment: Put another way, you asked "Is there a better way to solve this problem?" But what *is* the problem. You've presented a solution to *a* problem and asked how to implement that solution more efficiently. But what is the *original* problem you are trying to solve? In other words, what's the use case you're implementing? See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: What Levensthein distance algorithm do you use ? You can do invariant reductions so it may be even faster than the naive one written in C.

Answer (score 1):

Found this interesting article by adding precompute to your question:

http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=114

Code is in Python but should be possible to translate.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the letters in each word in both lists. Then intersect the two lists. Consider candidates to be near the point of intersection. Afterwards reverse sort the letters in both lists and repeat the process. This should narrow the list of candidates down significantly, so you only have to make about 6-12 Levenshtein comparisons instead of a million for each word.

Comment: You might throw away the minimum candidate. How to avoid that?

Comment: Brute force search 1 million x 1000 comparisons

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all

Comment: You cannot get something for nothing. I have explained the practical way to solve your problem. There is no way to get an exact match except by using an algorithm that integrated the matching algorithm with an intersector, and that kind of algorithm would be EXTREMELY complicated. You could spend months working on it. Your best course of action is to implement the simple solution I outlined above.

Comment: It was not my question. There's actually lots of material out there on approximate string matching, OP is certainly not the first to have this problem

Answer (score 0):

I realise that it is a couple of weeks since you posted your question and that you might already have worked out a sensible solution. Nonetheless, in searching for solutions to a similar problem, I not only came across your problem but also a library called [SimString](http://www.chokkan.org/software/simstring/), developed by Naoaki Okazaki. The library is written in C++ but Okazaki describes how to set up appropriate Ruby bindings. You might need to change your data structure a little in order to use the library most efficiently, but it appears that it would do what you want. I am hopeful that it will prove useful in solving my own problem.